# Linux installation says unallocated space is unusable

Tags: windows-7, linux, installation, multi-boot

I have 3 primary partitions, 1 extended already. Here's how my current disk management looks like:

[image]

As you can see, I have WinRE(F), System Reserved, C:, and D: (where all my installers, music, games, etc. reside).

Any way I can make this work without messing up my Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

I made WinRE to a Primary Partition (from Extended), then resized D: with EASEUS Partition Manager, then made D a Logical Partition.  On my linux installer, I then chose D: and resized it accordingly (linux can be installed inside an extended partition as a logical partition).

Answer (score 1):

To have more than 4 partitions, you need to use extended ones.
An extended partition is a primary partition divided into one or more sub-partitions.

Your extended partition is at the begining of your disk. This is very unusual. You can't extend or divide it to use the space at the end of your disk.

You should use a partition manager to modify this:
- convert your first partition to primary
- convert your last partition to extended
You will then be able to use your whole disk.

It is wize to backup your datas before.
Idealy, just clone your disk to another.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert a partition into an extended partition.  The hardware specs for IDEs limits the number of primary partitions to four.  The extended partition is a kind of primary partition that contains a chain of partitions.  So if you have 20 partitions in the drive, it looks through a chain of 20 partitons.